# Reflection.Emit - access and initialize fields

Tags: c#, constructor, reflection.emit, system.reflection

What I Want to do is to save all static field values of a static class in a dynamically created, non static class with non static fields.
The creation of the class works and I can acces the fields from outside the class `DynamicObject` but inside my constructor this doesnt work. The initialisation of the fields dont work. The loop is skipped because it doesnt find any fieldinfos.
I checked all members with all bindingflags (instance, static, public, nonpublic) but it dont find anything.

The question is Why? And how can I initialize the fields of my dynamically created class?

```
public class DynamicObject
    {
        public Type GeneratedType;
        public object Instance;
        public DynamicObject(Type BaseType)
        {
            //create object with Name: BaseType.Name + "_dynamic", in module "dynamic in assembly "dynamic"
            System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder tb = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new System.Reflection.AssemblyName("dynamic"), System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave).DefineDynamicModule("dynamic").DefineType(BaseType.Name + "_" + "dynamic", System.Reflection.TypeAttributes.Public);
            foreach (System.Reflection.FieldInfo fi in BaseType.GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static))
            {
                //create public field-definitions with identical Name
                tb.DefineField(fi.Name, fi.FieldType, System.Reflection.FieldAttributes.Public);
            }
            //save type
            this.GeneratedType = tb.CreateType();
            //create Instance with standard constructor: public <Type>_dynamic()
            this.Instance = tb.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(new object[] { });
            //initialize fields through BaseType fields
            foreach (System.Reflection.FieldInfo fi in this.Instance.GetType().GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public))
            {
                //load value from static variables
                fi.SetValue(this.Instance, BaseType.GetField(fi.Name).GetValue(null));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you sure the static class you're trying to "clone" *has* any public fields? Also, make sure to use `BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance` in the *second* foreach.

Comment: It worked for me when I removed the System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public flag on the second foreach cycle

Comment: @luaan Yes the BaseType has 4 public static fields. Tested with additional Instance BindingFlag and without BindingFlags in second loop. Seem to work (loop is iterating) but it seems that the code is called two times. Usage of Instance from outside brings NullReference Exception. Seems to be an issue with an static constructor of the BaseType. Without it works like a charm. So the BindingFlags do the trick. But why I had to use the additional Instance flag. In older cases I dont had to use it?

Comment: Which part of the code seems to be called twice? And since you're using unsafe code, it's perfectly possible that something doesn't work the way you'd expect - it *might* be that the static constructor isn't called properly when using reflection, for example; I'm not sure. You always have to use `BindingFlags.Instance` to get instance members - *however*, the default is `BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public`, so if you use the overload without binding flags, it uses that.

Comment: Sorry about that with calling two times. so I actually called it a second one by myself. Actually someone who clarify the usage of BindingFlags. :) thanks